# Cursor changes appearance and position in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, mouse-cursor

I've had this issue for a while and no amount of updating or rebooting seems to make it go away.

This is for a Lenovo Yoga 720 laptop with Windows 10 Family Edition.

Once in a while, for no reason that I can discern, the mouse pointer changes appearance, to a low-resolution version of a pointer with a blue circle above, as seen here :

[image]

The image of this cursor is also misplaced : while I can still use the mouse properly, the image of this cursor is about halfway further up the screen, making it difficult to know where the cursor physically is.

I have no clue as to the source of this bug and googling it is fairly difficult. Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lastly I did find the solution.

Lenovo's technical support suggested me to disable Lenovo Utility ,which solved this problem.

Do it yourself and you won't lose anything important when it comes to your computer's abilities.

Cheers